# How to I get summary statistics by rows while using Pandas df.describe() ,

Tags: python, pandas

I have issues when trying to get summary statistics from my dataframe.

I need the function to calculate all the summary statistics by rows.

for example, mean = adding up all the values in a row and divided by the number of observations in a row

Comment: you should show your input dataframe, and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn rows into columns and then use describe:

```
df.T.describe()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean df.describe().T, right?